# Need help installing Vulkan drivers on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers

I need to install the Vulkan drivers so certain GUI libraries in Rust will function properly.

I found my current driver info with:

```
(base) nexus@Lanny:~$ lspci -k | grep -A 2 -i "VGA"
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF106 [GeForce GTS 450] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] GF106 [GeForce GTS 450]
    Kernel driver in use: nouveau
```

and:

```
(base) nexus@Lanny:~$ sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00000DC4sv00001462sd00002360bc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GF106 [GeForce GTS 450]
driver   : nvidia-304 - third-party free
driver   : nvidia-340 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

Then I did the following:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
$ sudo apt upgrade
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install nvidia-graphics-drivers-396 nvidia-settings vulkan vulkan-utils
```

Which gave me this error:

```
E: Unable to locate package nvidia-graphics-drivers-396
E: Unable to locate package vulkan
```

Not sure what to do. Please advise.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

just try this:

`sudo apt install nvidia-settings vulkan-utils`